# How do I read data with special characters (e.g. "¼") from SQL

Tags: r

I am using the ODBC library to connect a SQL database and my data has some character fields which have values such as: "EX83 ¼ 4.3". This seems to import into R fine, however the "¼" character looks to be converted to: " � " so after I am ready to export the data base I use `dbWriteTable` and get the error: `invalid multibyte string, element 869907`

Does anyone know how I can fix this? The issue seems to exist the moment I import the table so I assume it would be better to fix it at that stage? The values seem to be rendered correctly in the SQL table.

Comment: You need to declare an appropriate character encoding inside the database and for the database connection.

Comment: @KonradRudolph thank you that was it. Feel free to post as an answer and I can accept